# How to pass password to shell script in terminal from reading the password from some txt file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I had 8 Servers and I need to copy files from my servers to One different server, for this purpose I had written a shell script to copy all the files from the servers using scp command, so for this it is asking for password for each and every time. To avoid this

1. Can it be possible to pass the password  to the shell script in the command prompt by reading the password value from some file?
2. I had tried using sshpass also but it is not solving the problem. Apart from this solution, other solution will be helpful.

I am new to shell script to need some help. Please if anyone knows how to achieve this, please share...thanks.

Comment: Don't. A password in a text file is a security hole. Set up passwordless ssh authentication (info in any ssh guide).

Comment: Generate a key with ssh-keygen and send it to your target server. Put it in the .ssh/authorized_keys file. Activate the publickey authentification in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart the sshd daemon.

Comment: already tried this ssh-keygen, it will not work in my case.

Comment: can i send password to the terminal from the shell script itself?